# Assuming a; c; f are all non-zero, use row reduction to work out the general form for $A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices

Let $A = \left[ \begin{array} { c c c } { a } & { 0 } & { 0 } \\ { b } & { c } & { 0 } \\ { d } & { e } & { f } \end{array} \right]$ where $a , b , c , d , e , f$ are real numbers.is called a lower triangular matrix.)

Assuming $a , c , f$ are all non-zero, use row reduction to work out the general form
for $A ^ { - 1 }$ . (The answer will be a matrix each of whose entries is a formula involving a,
$b , c , d , e$ and $f$ or some subset of these variables.

Could I get a hint on how one can do row reduction with letters

Comment: Your row operations will result in expressions with variables in them.  For example, if you something like row_3 - row_1, you'll get a row with [(d-a), e, f]

Answer (score 1):

The inverse $B=A^{-1}$ is the matrix such that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
b & c & 0 \\
d & e & f 
\end{bmatrix}
B
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or putting in some variables 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
b & c & 0 \\
d & e & f 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B_{1} & B_{2} & B_{3} \\
B_{4} & B_{5} & B_{6} \\
B_{7} & B_{8} & B_{9} \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You could write out the 9 equations that result from this matrix multiplication and you'll start getting $B$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.  For example,
$$
aB_1+0B_4+0B_7=1
$$
This shows that $B_1=\frac{1}{a}$.  Then you can keep solving this system to uncover $B$.

As @amd pointed to in the comments and as Robert also showed, the above could be written as an augmented matrix 
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    a & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    b & c & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
on which you can perform row operations.  For example, start by multiplying the first row by $\frac{1}{a}$ to get
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
    b & c & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
From here you might multiply row two by $\frac{1}{c}$ to get 
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{b}{c} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{c} & 0 \\
    d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Subtract $\frac{b}{c}$ times the first row from the second to get
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{b}{ac} & \frac{1}{c} & 0 \\
    d & e & f & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right]
$$
and keep working toward reducing the left hand side to $I_3$.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to address the actual question being asked: “... how one can do row reduction with letters.”

Comment: I think it does hint at it, since the solution of this system I suggested for B is implicitly row operations.  Do you think that the question intended for the row operations to apply to $A$?  Possibly it did.

Comment: I’d guess that the row reduction is meant to be applied to $[A\mid I]$, which is a standard method for computing $A^{-1}$. The OP’s issue, however, appears to be that some of the entries of $A$ are variables instead of specific numbers.

Comment: Right, what I have above is equivalent to what you've written as an augmented matrix, and the algebra is equivalent to the row-reductions on that augmented matrix.  I can add some more to it to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The general technique is to use row reduction to convert $A$ to the identity matrix while tracking the results of the same operations on $I$.  So, for example, start by multiplying the first row (of both $A$ and $I$) by $1/a$.

The next step will be to subtract $b$ times the (new) first row from the second row, and then you'll divide the (new) second row by $c$.